# query PDO bind not return in datetime

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this query does not return due to a datetime search.
How to use bind_param in datetime?
thanks

```
$offset = ($pagina - 1)*2;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$last30days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' -30 day'));
$prepare = $conn->prepare('SELECT `pedido`.`numero`, `pedido`.`dataCriacao`, `clientes`.`nome`, `pedido`.`totalvenda`, `pedido`.`situacao` 
                                FROM `pedido`
                                INNER JOIN `clientes` ON `clientes`.`codigo` = `pedido`.`clienteCodigo`
                                WHERE `pedido`.`dataCriacao` > :tempo
                                LIMIT :offset,2 
                            ');
    $prepare->bindValue(':tempo', $last30days, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prepare->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepare->execute();
```

Comment: There is nothing special in binding a datetime. It is bound the same way as any other variable. If your query returned no results it means there is either an error or no data to match the input parameters

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "due to a datetime search"? What have you tried to debug your problem?